# How to set the date in materialize datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, material-design

I am using materializecss.com Datepicker. When i try to set date with jquery, the date doesn't get set. Here is my Code :-

```
// Materialize Date Picker
    window.picker = $('.datepicker').pickadate({
        selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
        selectYears: 100, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'    
    });

<input type="text" id="Date" class="datepicker" />
```

On Click event of a Button , I am setting the date :-

```
$("#Date").val('23/01/2015');
```

When i open the datepicker it shows me today's date.

How to set the date in materialize datepicker?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Materialize datepicker is a modified [pickadate.js](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/) picker.

Accodging to their [API docs](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api/), this is how to set the picker:

1. Get the picker:

```js
var $input = $('.datepicker').pickadate()

// Use the picker object directly.
var picker = $input.pickadate('picker')
```

1. Set the date:

```js
// Using arrays formatted as [YEAR, MONTH, DATE].
picker.set('select', [2015, 3, 20])

// Using JavaScript Date objects.
picker.set('select', new Date(2015, 3, 30))

// Using positive integers as UNIX timestamps.
picker.set('select', 1429970887654)

// Using a string along with the parsing format (defaults to `format` option).
picker.set('select', '2016-04-20', { format: 'yyyy-mm-dd' })
```

Comment: I have defined the datepicker in `custom.js` file. When i try to set date as  per your answer from outside `custom.js` it shows me error :- `Uncaught ReferenceError: picker is not defined`

Comment: I declared `global variable` like this :-`window.picker = $input.pickadate('picker');` .. Now its working..thanks.

Answer (score 14):

just add the format you want your date looks like in the attributes of your element.

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
    selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
    selectYears: 15, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy' });
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use methods of datepicker which are present in `V1.0.0-rc.2`.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var options = {
    defaultDate: new Date(2018, 1, 3),
    setDefaultDate: true
  };
  var elems = document.querySelector('.datepicker');
  var instance = M.Datepicker.init(elems, options);
  // instance.open();
  instance.setDate(new Date(2018, 2, 8));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input type="text" class="datepicker">
```

`defaultDate` will set a default Date that will be shown in input-field of datepicker without even opening the picker.

[image]

`instance.setDate()` will select the date in datepicker when you'll open it.

[image]

**Note-** `new Date(year, monthIndex [, day [, hours [, minutes [, seconds [, milliseconds]]]]]);`

The argument `monthIndex` is 0-based. This means that `January = 0` and `December = 11`

[Picker - Materialize](https://materializecss.com/pickers.html)

[MDN - Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: setDefaultDate: true does not result in an output with the default date in display. Any workarounds for that?

Comment: I have two date fields. When I added this script the calendar is showing only for the first field, not for the second field. Any hacks to show calendar for second field too?

Comment: Figured out!! just change the class for second field and added into the script. It works like a charm!

Answer (score 6):

Alle answers with pickadate() don't work anymore in newer versions of Materialize. The method is now named datepicker(). Here's my code snippet:

```
var element = document.querySelector('.datepicker');
M.Datepicker.getInstance(element).setDate(new Date(2018,8,7), true);
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the docs [materializecss.com](https://materializecss.com/pickers.html)
Check the Date format options.

```
// date picker
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.datepicker').datepicker( {"format":'dd-mm-yyyy'} ).datepicker("setDate", new Date());

});
```

You can remove and change the code to below if you do not need current date as highlighted in calendar,

```
// date picker
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.datepicker').datepicker( {"format":'dd-mm-yyyy'});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in the options that you want to default to on init.
For example the below js code would work with markup:

```js
const elems2 = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
  for (element of elems2) {
    const date = element.dataset.defaultDate
    if (date !== undefined) {
      M.Datepicker.init(element, {defaultDate: new Date(date), yearRange: 15})
    }
    else {
       M.Datepicker.init(element, {})
    }
  }
```

```html
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
           
           
           
         <input class="validate datepicker valid" required="required" data-default-date="2009-07-11 10:14:47 -0700" name='picker' type="text">
         <label for="picker" class="active">Date Picker 10 years ago</label>
```

Comment: setDefaultDate sets the default input value, but I dont think this was the question

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `angular`, or something similar, in order to manage your web application and you are not able to instance the `Datepicker` object, according to the [materialize](https://materializecss.com/pickers.html) documentation, using `jQuery` you can refer to these methods of the object:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
```

In the first parameter, in this case `setDate`, you may specify the method name that you are about to use. In the second parameter, in this case `new Date()`, you will pass the value to the function (if any).

In the example, that line will update the date of all datepickers with the class `.datepicker` to today.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var $input = $('.datepicker').pickadate()

// Use the picker object directly.
var picker = $input.pickadate('picker')
```

### Heading

Comment: While this code _may_ answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#elementID').pickadate('picker').set('select', '21/05/2017', { format: 'dd/mm/yyyy' }).trigger("change");
```

This should suit your needs in one line. Trigger change you may need or maybe not, depends your situation, like me i need it for validation to trigger. Also include with format date just in case some people need it.

Answer (score -2):

watch out for your css and js version of materialize:
if in the `<head>` you have

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
```

then stick to it having same JS version
so that you can use `$('.datepicker').pickadate('picker').set('select','your parsed date',{format:'your format'}).trigger('change')`

If version is 1.0.0 then you will have to use 
`$('.datepicker').datepicker();`

Comment: also add $('.datepicker').on('mousedown',function(event){ event.preventDefault(); }) if using it in Chrome (known issue: [link](https://github.com/InfomediaLtd/angular2-materialize/issues/444))