# materialize css datepicker options

Tags: javascript, datepicker, materialize

// Materialize Date Picker

```
this.instanceDatepicker = new M.Datepicker(this.elDatepicker.nativeElement, {
        defaultDate: new Date(2018,5,4),
        setDefaultDate: true,
        selectMonths: true,
        selectYears: 200, 
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
    });

<input type="text" id="Date" class="datepicker" />
```

In the options listed above, `defaultDate` and `setDefaultDate` fail to show the desired date populated in the input. Anything that I may be doing wrong or is this buggy?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the date in materialize datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30324552/how-to-set-the-date-in-materialize-datepicker)

Comment: That is precisely where i went initially but the option mentioned there is exactly the one which doesn't work and hence this question @SudharshanNair

Comment: Have you tried the approved answer of above link?

Comment: sure have but nothing seems to help.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: here i created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jq984ty0/

Comment: Try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jq984ty0/4/   and let me know, if its working or not ?

Comment: this is definitely working. but again why sould i have to use .set() when there is an option that says defaultDate and setDefaultDate? any ideas on that? post your current fiddle below and i'll upvote it. :)

Comment: Its not for input, Its for `The initial date to view when first opened.`. I think this should resolve your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these lines and it will work

```
var $input = $('.datepicker').pickadate();
var picker = $input.pickadate('picker');
picker.set('select', new Date(2018, 5, 4));
```