# MaterializeCSS datepicker: setDate does not update the view

Tags: javascript, datepicker, materialize

Using MaterializeCSS 1 rc2, I try to update the date of my DatePicker from Javascript.

My HTML

```
<form action="#" novalidate>
   <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="date" id="datepicker">
</form>
```

My JS

```
function changeDate(date) {
    /* date is a javascript Date object */
    var datepicker = document.getElementById('datepicker');
    var instance = M.Datepicker.getInstance(datepicker);
    instance.setDate(date);
}
```

Looking at the console, all the variables are set to their expected value. When I click on the DatePicker, that's also the expected date which is displayed (the one I use in `changeDate`). But the text in the input field does not change...

Comment: is date an instance of Date?

Comment: yes. If it helps, when I look at the values in FormData (cause this is part of a form), the date is not the right one.

Comment: Could you upload your code on somewhere like plunker or jsfiddle?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51562552/8437974

Comment: Feel free to flag an answer as "Solution"

Answer (score 8):

My friend, you have found a bug in MaterializeCSS!

I can suggest you my workaround: call `instance._finishSelection()` after calling `instance.setDate()` to see your changes.

- https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/6074

Comment: Thanks man, that was the answer I was looking for (for a really frustrating long time)!

Answer (score 2):

Currently ("materialize-css": "^1.0.0") you can achieve that with: `instance.setInputValue`:

Typescript code:

```
const datepickerInstance = M.Datepicker.getInstance(datepickerEl[0]);
datepickerInstance.setDate(date);
datepickerInstance.setInputValue();
```