# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).pickadate is not a function

Tags: jquery, html, materialize

i'm currently developing a simple web project. I have a page who has a simple form where the person put his name, his birthday,and his univerisity degree. I'm using materialize and jquery. But it has been a nightmare, because i can't get the date (birthday) properly with these two. I always get this error :

`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).pickadate is not a function`

Here is my html :

```js
$(function() {

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datepicker').pickadate({
      selectMonths: true,
      selectYears: 20
    });
    $('select').material_select();
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/materialize/css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title>EscolAlura</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/materialize/js/inicializar.js"></script>



</head>

<body class="grey lighten-3">
  <div id="formularioEdicao" class="container">
    <h3 class="main-title center">Cadastrar Aluno</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <form class="col s12" action="#" th:action="@{/aluno/salvar}" th:object="${aluno}" method="post">
        <div class="section">
          <h5>Dados Básicos</h5>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <input id="nome" type="text" th:field="*{nome}" />
              <label for="nome">Nome</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <input id="dataNascimento" type="date" class="datepicker" th:field="*{dataNascimento}" />
              <label for="dataNascimento">Dt. Nascimento</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <input id="curso" type="text" class="validate" th:field="*{curso.nome}" />
              <label for="curso">Curso</label>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <!-- Fim SECTION Dados Basicos -->

        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12 center">
            <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Salvar Aluno</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- Fim do formulario de edicao -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/materialize/js/materialize.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[My page in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFWyU.png)

Anyone knows how to solve this problem ? Thx

Comment: From where is `.pickadate()` defined?

Comment: did you try moving `<script type="text/javascript" src="/materialize/js/materialize.js"></script>` into the `<head>` before your `inicializar.js` inclusion?

Comment: Always make sure you add plug-in you use first and then the scripts which initiates the function. It depends on order of scripts included

Comment: @AdamChubbuck i think it's defined in materialize.min.js

Comment: Nowhere on the [materialize.js](https://materializecss.com/) site can I find anything about a function called `.pickadate()`

Comment: @esqew https://stackoverflow.com/a/30324855/8732818

Comment: @CalvinNunes Thanks for the link - was unaware of this convention

Comment: I also didn't know, but I did a research because I think it was weird that the code working even without saying anything in the docs... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order you load your scripts are very important.

When using jQuery, starts with it, load it before all. Then goes with the other plugins, then with your custom JS files.

See below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.datepicker').pickadate({
        selectMonths: true, 
        selectYears: 20 
      });
      
    $('select').material_select();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" />

<div id="formularioEdicao" class="container">
    <h3 class="main-title center">Cadastrar Aluno</h3>
    <div class="row">
        <form class="col s12" action="#" th:action="@{/aluno/salvar}" th:object="${aluno}" method="post">
            <div class="section">
                <h5>Dados Básicos</h5>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <input id="nome" type="text" th:field="*{nome}" />
                        <label for="nome">Nome</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <input id="dataNascimento" type="date" class="datepicker" th:field="*{dataNascimento}"/>
                        <label for="dataNascimento">Dt. Nascimento</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <input id="curso" type="text" class="validate" th:field="*{curso.nome}"  />
                        <label for="curso">Curso</label>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div> <!-- Fim SECTION Dados Basicos -->

            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12 center">
                    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Salvar Aluno</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hey calvin, thx for your help. 'm running some tests and it was not the order of the imports, although they're not in the right order. In fact it seens that my materialize.min.js it's not working properly. I used yours and my code started working. Now i have to see why he's not working, because i've downloaded from the materialize website, and it's the same version as yours.

Comment: so, probaly yours was or corrupted, or deprecated or not loading correct. But if it's working now is that counts. If you think this is the right answer for you, you can mark the "v" in the left of my answer to check it as correct one. Thanks

Comment: I think i'm loading correctly because the browser would give me an error wouldn't ? Where did you find those links ? Thx calvin

Comment: If the file was not loading you'll see that in the console log in the dev tools.
Here's the site https://cdnjs.com/  here you get a lot of libreries loading directly from the web, no need for download the libraries. sometimes may not be the best option, but sometimes is useful.