# How to add Clear and Today buttons in materializecss datepicker?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, materialize

I'm using [materializecss](http://archives.materializecss.com/0.100.2/forms.html) version 1.0.0-beta version and I need to use datepicker functionality. Datepicker is working fine but I need to add following buttons to my calendar.

- Clear : Reset the calendar
- Today : Select today as selected date

In older version I can simply add that by adding today and clear options. But in new version it seems like they are not working.

If someone can give me a solution or even link to comprehensive documentation would be helpful.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use below official link of materialize css

https://materializecss.com/pickers.html

And can use

```
"setDefaultDate" option to set default date on init
```

"showClearBtn" property is also there

Comment: showclearbtn is working. thanks. But i cant get the setDeafaultDate option clearly

Comment: Check this for default date - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51562552/8437974