# How to add an event date in Date Picker Materialize?

Tags: javascript, datepicker, materialize

I'm trying to add event's date in the calendar of the day picker using the method that Materialize suggest but isn't working for me or maybe I'm doing something wrong.

[Materialize Date Picker](https://materializecss.com/pickers.html)

```
var elems = document.querySelector('.datepicker')
var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems, {
      events: [new Date('2018,12,12').toLocaleDateString()]
    }
```

---

**EDIT-**

*Solution to my Problem-*

Down below is the code of my final working result, by the way I used this date format ('2018,12,12')  because it is easier for me to figure that **12** is equals to **december** rather than 11 in this date format (2018,11,25) .

I have also added other parameters which are working perfectly.

I appreciate your help, Thanks Germa V.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    let eventsDates = [
        new Date('2018,12,1').toDateString(),
        new Date('2018,12,2').toDateString()
    ];
    let disableListDate = [
        new Date('2018,12,3').toDateString(),
        new Date('2018,12,4').toDateString()
    ];

    let optionsDate = {
        defaultDate: defaultDate,
        setDefaultDate: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        events: eventsDates,
        disableWeekends: false,
        autoClose: false,
        showDaysInNextAndPreviousMonths: false,
        showClearBtn: true,
        i18n:{
            months: 
            ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agost', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Noviem..', 'Diciemb..'],
            monthsShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Agos', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
            weekdays: ['Dom','Lun', 'Mar', 'Mie', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sab']
        },
        format: 'dd-mmm-yyyy',
        onSelect() {
            if (optionsDate.events.includes(this.date.toDateString())) {
                alert('Event Date');
            }
        },

        disableDayFn(date) {
            if(disableListDate.includes(date.toDateString()))
                return true
            else
                return false
        },

        parse(){

        }
    }

    let elems = document.querySelector('.datepicker');
    let instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems, optionsDate);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how you set a date in `Date()`, if you want to know how to set date in Datepicker function then you can check this answer --> [How to set date in Materialize Datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51562552/8437974)

```
var optionsDate = {
    events: [new Date(2018, 11, 20).toDateString(),
    new Date(2018, 11, 21).toDateString()],
    onSelect() {
        if (optionsDate.events.includes(this.date.toDateString())) {
            console.log('Event Date');
        }
    }
}
var elemsDate = document.querySelector(".datepicker");
var instanceDate = M.Datepicker.init(elemsDate, optionsDate);
```

Comment: I see what you are doing, let me try and I let you know.

Thanks Germa V.